# Change source array of ng-repeat by change in DOM positions

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to render a couple of div from an array of objects.
Then using a jquery selector on a button inside the div's, the position of two divs can be swapped.The logic applied is using $(selector).prev().before() to move the contents.

How can this change be made to reflect the positions of the divs in the array ??

Or is their another way to manipulate the source array by change in the DOM positions ?

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/qudilafura/edit?html,js,output

How can the array be updated by change in DOM positions.It's Easy the Other Way Round, but for some reason, I have to use the jQuery construct.

Comment: 2 questions. First, can you add a jsFiddle? They come in very handy on these types of questions. Second, are you changing the content of the array, or the position (layout) of the divs? Or both? On click of the button, does only the layout change, or does the array contents change as well?

Comment: Only the layout changes.
But subsequent digest cycles should cause the list to re-gain original order right?
But that doesn't happen, so the order in array must've been changed as well.But that doesnt happen as well !!!

Answer (score 0):

Dont work on the dom. Just change the modell.

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){

  $scope.list=[{name:'item1',prop:'prop1'},
               {name:'item2',prop:'prop2'},
               {name:'item3',prop:'prop4'}
              ];


     $scope.up=function(pos){
          if(pos < 1) return;
           var newIndex = pos - 1;
           var movedItem = $scope.list[pos];
            $scope.list[pos] = $scope.list[newIndex];
            $scope.list[newIndex] =  movedItem;
     };

});
```

Html

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='myctrl'>
  <div id='collection'>
  <div class='item' ng-repeat='item in list'>
     {{item.name}}
    <button class='usp' ng-click='up($index)' >^Move Up^</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  {{list}}
  <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to reorder the array, and when you reorder the array, the DOM will update. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/quresunisi/edit?html,js,console,output) an update to your code, very similar to Malcolm's code, who just answered.

Basically, you have very few reasons to use jQuery with Angular. If you're using Angular, think more about changing the data, not the DOM. Let the 2 way bindings of Angular handle the DOM updates. If you really need to interact with the DOM, you probably don't need Angular, and it can just be a jQuery project. Nothing wrong with that, they just do really different things.

Hope this helps.